# Play system sound on push notification

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

I display the list of sound retrieved from "/System/Library/Audio/UISounds".When user select any sound, I send the name of sound to the server. When server send the push notification , it configure that name in payload , 
But still iOS play the default sound. What Do I have to do to play the selected sound.

Comment: As far as I know you can't play system sounds on push notification (except the default sound) in iOS.

Comment: What if I keep the file in app's bundle.?

Comment: That's suppose to work.

Comment: it is possible in local notification.

Comment: @manageinvite was you able to copy a selected system sound to the app bundle?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible in local notification. will attached in the payload, key ="sound"

```
 aps =     
{
    alert = "test example notification message";
    sound = "example.caf";
};
```

example.caf file import in your xcode project.

you will try the same concept may be it will works.